# ExtJS 4.2 - Error Loading Store From Command - Data Returned From Service - MVC Setup

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am having all sorts of issues learning ExtJS (I am a flex Dev). Currently, I am unsure how to load a store from a command. I have a command where I make a service call and get the data. I then want to load the model with this data (from inside the command).

My code...

PhoneCallsLoadCommand.js:  (COMMAND)

```
Ext.define('DG.controller.PhoneCallsLoadCommand', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['PhoneCalls'],
    models: ['PhoneCall'],

    views: [
        'PhoneCallListView'
    ],

    init: function () {
        var url2 = "https://MyServiceURLWSDL";
        var pl = new SOAPClientParameters();
        pl.add("arg0", false);

        SOAPClient.invoke(url2, "gePaymentsMethod", pl, true, getDataCallback);

        function getDataCallback(response) {
        // This is where I want to load the response data into the Model
            var store = Ext.getStore('phoneCallsStore');
            store.loadData(response);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the response XML data returned from the service call:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dlwmin:getPaymentsMethod xmlns:dlwmin="http://blahblah.com/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <return>
            <contents>
               <eftAcctNo>501014635986</eftAcctNo>
               <empSsn>122400724</eftAcctRoutNo>
            </contents>
            <contents>
               <eftAcctNo></eftAcctNo>
               <empSsn></eftAcctRoutNo>
            </contents>
            <contents>
               <eftAcctNo></eftAcctNo>
               <empSsn></eftAcctRoutNo>
            </contents>
            <status>0</status>
         </return>
      </dlwmin:getPaymentsMethod>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to populate this response data into my model so that I can use it in my grid.

PhoneCall.js:  (MODEL)

```
Ext.define('DG.model.PhoneCall', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        idProperty: 'phoneCallModel',
        fields: [
            {name: "eftAcctNo", type: "string"},
            {name: "empSsn", type: "string"}
        ]
    }
});
```

PhoneCalls.js  (STORE)

```
Ext.define('DG.store.PhoneCalls', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        storeId: 'phoneCallsStore',
        model: 'DG.model.PhoneCall',
        autoLoad: false
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            record: 'contents',
            //rootProperty: 'return'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        'load' : function() {
            console.log("Making Service Call...");
        }
    }
});
```

In the Command, when I do this:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('phoneCallsStore');
            store.loadData(response);
```

I get the following error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'loadData' of undefined

Can someone tell me how to load that response data into the model? My View is a grid that points to the model.

PhoneCallListView.js  (VIEW)

```
Ext.define('DG.view.PhoneCallListView' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.phoneCallListView',
    title: 'Phone Calls DataGrid',

    // we no longer define the Phone Calls store in the 'initComponent' method
    store: 'PhoneCalls',

    initComponent: function() {
        this.columns = [
            {header: 'Eft Acct No', dataIndex: 'eftAcctNo', flex:1},
            {header: 'Emp Ssn', dataIndex: 'empSsn', flex:1},
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

FYI - I wasn't able to get the Store to make the service call using the ajax proxy, so I found it easy to use soapclient.js.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me:

```
    function getDataCallback(req, r) {
        var store = Ext.getStore('PhoneCalls');
        store.loadRawData(r);
        store.sync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The line: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'loadData' of undefined` tells me that your store is not defined.  Since your store is called `DG.store.PhoneCalls`, you should be using `Ext.getStore('PhoneCalls')`, making sure that you have used the `stores: ['PhoneCalls']` config in your controller.

And while you may have found trouble using the Ajax proxy, you really should try to find a way to make it work.  The way you are attempting to load the store here is very much a hack.  Perhaps an `XmlStore` is what you should be using: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.XmlStore

Comment: If you look at my code above, I have stores: ['PhoneCalls'] in the command. Also, I have tried Ext.getStore('PhoneCalls') and also using the id of the Store. Neither work.

Comment: As I said, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'loadData' of undefined` means that your store is not retrieved properly.  Try moving your `stores: ['PhoneCalls']` line to your app.js gile.